# Pyqt5 QWebEngineView and QWebEnginePage

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine

Can Someone please explain the usage of QWebEngineView and QWebEnginePage in PyQt5. 
I want to intercept all the requests and thereby override the acceptNavigationRequest() method belonging to the QWebEnginePage class. But I am not using any QWebEnginePage object but directly implementing the QWebEngineView.

I have an input field and i am loading URL from that field using this method.

```
def loadURL(self):
    self.load(QUrl(self.URL))
    print('Loading ', self.URL)
```

But the links that are followed from the loaded page are what i need to handle seperately. How do i do that.

Comment: The only way to do it is to subclass `QWebEnginePage` and reimplement `acceptNavigationRequest`.

Comment: How to use the QWebEnginePage object inside the QwebEngineView class?

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188513/catch-link-clicks-in-qtwebview-and-open-in-default-browser/49499548#49499548

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a sublcass of `QWebEnginePage` reimplementing `acceptNavigationRequest`:

```
class WebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage):

  def acceptNavigationRequest(self, qUrl, requestType, isMainFrame):
    # return True to allow navigation, False to block it
    return True
```

Now in your `QWebEngineView` assign your new class as page using `setPage`:

```
class WebEngineView(QWebEngineView):

  def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.setPage(WebEnginePage(self))
```